# How can I exclude commas, brackets, and braces when printing? (Python)

Tags: python

I would like my print statement for the code below to exclude commas, brackets, and braces. Like this:

THREE-NOTE TRIADS PROGRESSION:
D♯
C
F♭ᵒ
C♯

Starting Position:
632​ ​Root Position

```
# Three-Note Triad Generator
import random
roots = ("A", "A♯", "B", "B♯", "C", "C♯", "D", "D♯", "E", "E♯", "F", "F♯", "G", "G♯", "A♭", "B♭", "C♭", "D♭", "E♭", "F♭", "G♭")
triad_types = ('', '⁻', '⁺', 'ᵒ')
three_string_groups = ('654', '653', '652', '651', '643', '642', '641', '632', '631', '621', '543', '542', '541', '532','531', '521', '432', '431', '421', '321')
inversion = ("Root Position", "1st Inversion", "Second Inversion")

print("\n\n\nTHREE-NOTE TRIADS PROGRESSION:")
print((random.sample(roots, 1)) + (random.sample(triad_types, 1)))
print((random.sample(roots, 1)) + (random.sample(triad_types, 1)))
print((random.sample(roots, 1)) + (random.sample(triad_types, 1)))
print((random.sample(roots, 1)) + (random.sample(triad_types, 1)))
print("\nStarting Position:")
print((random.sample(three_string_groups, 1)) + (random.sample(inversion, 1)))
```

Comment: `print(random.choice(roots), random.choice(triad_types))`…?

Comment: random.sample returns a list. As k==1 in your case, try using random.choice. Either that or random.sample(roots,1)[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking with `*` to get the strings from the list.

For example:

```py
print(*(random.sample(roots, 1) + random.sample(triad_types, 1)))
```

Which prints:

```
B♭
```

Comment: This unpacking method can be used when you might need to use `random.sample` with size > 1. If you always use size of 1 then choice is better and requires no unpacking as @deceze commented.